# Not able to loop through two child nodes simultaneously

Tags: xslt

**input xml:**

[image]

Required output format:

[image]

Using for-each we can traverse through all child tags under either "headers" or "objects"; but how to traverse through both tags and select values and combine them as shown above(just one weird example :)). By using xsl transformation. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Do you mean to repeat `entry1` on all 4 lines, or should it be `entry1, ...2, ...3, ...4`?  Also, very important, DO NOT post images of text. Post the text itself so it can be copied easily.  Posting images of text makes it much harder for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input** (*please post only text. easier to copy*)

```
<payload>
    <headers>
        <header>
            <name>entry1</name>
        </header>
        <header>
            <name>entry2</name>
        </header>
        <header>
            <name>entry3</name>
        </header>
        <header>
            <name>entry4</name>
        </header>
    </headers>
    <objects>
        <row>
            <value>1231</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>342</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>98789</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>6576</value>
        </row>
    </objects>
</payload>
```

**XSLT:** (there are many solutions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="objects">
            <xsl:for-each select="payload/objects/row">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                <entry name="{/payload/headers/header[$i]/name}" value="{value}"></entry>
            </xsl:for-each>            
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<objects>
   <entry name="entry1" value="1231"></entry>
   <entry name="entry2" value="342"></entry>
   <entry name="entry3" value="98789"></entry>
   <entry name="entry4" value="6576"></entry>
</objects>
```